# Default audio (Pygame.mixer and alsamixer) doesn't work when using sudo

Tags: sudo

I have a simple python file which plays a sound:

```
#sound_test.py
import pygame

#init sounds
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, 16, 2, 4096)
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

WAV = pygame.mixer.Sound("Music/4AM_cry.wav")
WAV.play()
```

EDIT: I've found that if I run `alsamixer` it shows the correct audio out but `sudo alsamixer` does not.

If I run `python3 soundtest.py` it works but `sudo python3 soundtest.py` does not.  What's going on?

P.S.  I have a USB DAC I'm using on a RPi.  It is set to the default audio card.

Comment: You probably have local configuration stored which superuser does not have inside it's own directory, hence configuration does not load. Use `strace` to find out why.

Answer (score 0):

I did not figure out how to make sudo use the correct default audio device but I did find a work around for my case.

By using `sudo -u someUserName python3 soundtest.py` I was able to run the python script from the profile it was working for.